# How to do a realm database migration during application update without deleting data using xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, realm, realm-migration

My question is straightforward. I don't know how to migrate my data to new schema. I added ShouldDeleteIfMigrationIsNeeded when getting Realm instance which is a wrong thing to do on production. When I tried to update our app, the whole data got erased. Good thing this is our first week so it's still okay if data is gone but not for the next time.

How to do proper migration? What to put code. Where to put code. When to trigger

Here is my code on instance

```
public class DAL_DBAccessVariables
{
    private const string databaseName = "dbname.realm";
    private static readonly string dbPath =
        Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);
    private static readonly RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(dbPath);

    public static Realm GetInstance()
    {
        RealmConfiguration config = DAL_DBAccessVariables.config;
        config.ShouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded = true;
        return Realm.GetInstance(config);
    }
}
```

Here is the sample usage

```
public class DAL_Branches : IDALCommands
{
    Realm realm;

    public DAL_Branches()
    {
        realm = DAL_DBAccessVariables.GetInstance();
    }

    public object selectSpecific(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return realm.All<t_Branches>().ToList().Find(o => o.Id == id);
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `config.ShouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded = true;` should be false, then you can check https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#performing-a-migration

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce I'll take note of that.

Comment: From your link. Since schemaversion needs to increment, does it mean that I have to create a migrationcallback every deployment with an update to db schema and it will run when migration is needed? :) 

Your link is so helpful. Thanks for it.